# Why is Haskell parsing comments?

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I have a really simple code (in GHC 8.10.4/`stack ghci` 17.12):

```
module T where

data D = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)

fn :: D -> Int
fn x =
  case x of
    A ->
      -- | Test
      1
    B -> 2
    C -> 3
```

The thing is, whether I replace `|` by `^` or use the multi-lines comment, I get this error:

```
T.hs:9:7: error: parse error on input ‘-- | Test’
  |
9 |       -- | Test
  |       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Does the parser mismatch my comment with something else? or is there a special syntax that look likes comments?

Comment: I can not reproduce this, with the given file, it is processed, so no compiler error.

Comment: I'm not a haskell expert, but are you really allowed to put a comment right in the middle of an expression like that?

Comment: You say you replace `|` with `^`, but the error message shows a `|`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it works without `|`

Comment: @chepner the error message match the code, of course, when I change it, the error message changes also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A comment starts with `--`. Comments that start with `-- |` are a special kind of comment for the documentation tool haddock, and are only allowed in certain places (and the location you put it is not one of them). GHC actually accepts your code. It is likely that the way you're building your program involves an invocation of haddock, which rejects misplaced `-- |` comments.

Solution: use `--` for plain comments, not `-- |`, which are for haddock.

```
    -- Test
```

Comment: Or, if you must have a vertical line, use `-- │` (U+2502 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL).